# Rebasing branch on top of branch that is ahead

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-config

I am trying to understand what happens in the following situation:

1. Branch out into FB from branch X
2. Branch X gets new commits
3. While being on FB, and without having made any changes on FB I now run `git rebase origin/X`
4. The result is clear: FB now looks identical to X again.

But I don’t really understand what happens here, does git simply replay the commits from X onto FB? Or is the reference to the base-commit simply changed?

I know that if I had made changes on FB, these commits would have been ‘moved’ to a new base-commit, but what happens exactly in the case where I don’t make any changes on my FB?

Comment: *does git simply replay the commits from X onto FB?* This *replaying* is actually [cherry picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) done internally.

Answer (score 0):

> does git simply replay the commits from X onto FB?

Yes.

If you compare this history of `FB` before and after the rebase you'll see the commit ids have all changed because the commits have been re-created.

The free *Pro Git* [includes diagrams](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) which makes this easier to follow.

Comment: The question states _While being on FB, without having made any changes_. So, your point about re-created commit IDs is kinda confusing.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb The commit id is a hash which incorporates the hashes of all parent commits, in the case of a rebase the parents change, so the re-created commits have different hashes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was able to convey my point. There are no commits which need to be re-created, in case of the scenario explained in the question. I just created a branch `new` from `base`, made new commits in `base`. Then `git rebase base` in `new`. No hashes were changed.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb in that case the rebase was a no-op. (I included a link which explains what rebase does in more detail than will fit in a [SO] answer, albeit details of what is included in the hash are covered in the chapter on low level details.)

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb thats what I was thinking as well, so in this case the added commits from base are just added/replayed on top of new?

Comment: Yes. That's what @Richard means by a no-op. Both the branches are just the same.